# Fastest way to find index of first character that is not equal in all strings

Tags: bash, shell, optimization

Say I have a couple of input lines like this

```
blablabla this is always the same 123
blablabla this is always the same 321
blablabla this is always the same 4242
blablabla this is al 242
blablabla this is always 2432
...
```

There is a suffix at the beginning that might or might not be identical to all substrings. It depends on some code the leads up to this point in my case. What I want to do is to strip away all leading characters that are identical to all the strings. In this case I want to have:

```
ways the same 123
ways the same 321
ways the same 4242
 242
ways 2432
...
```

I have a solution that outputs the correct result, but it's very slow. I require a solution in bash only. Any help would be appreciated.

[UPDATE] I edited my initial script to demonstrate the current solutions of this thread.

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup test data 
tempf=$( mktemp )
echo "blablabla this is always the same 123
blablabla this is always the same 321
blablabla this is always the same 4242
blablabla this is al 242
blablabla this is always 2432" > $tempf 

# BASELINE by myself 
find_index_baseline () {

    longest_line=$( cat $tempf | wc -L )  # determine end of iteration sequence 
    for i in $( seq 1 $longest_line ) # iterate over char at position i 
    do
        # find number of different chars by 
        #  - printing all data using echo 
        #  - cutting out the i'th character 
        #  - unique sort resulting character set 
        #  - count resulting characters 
        diffchars=$( cat $tempf | cut -c${i} | sort -u | wc -l )
        [ $diffchars -ge 2 ] && break # if more than 1 character, then break 
    done
    idx=$(( $i - 1 )) # save index 
    cat $tempf | while read line; do echo "${line:$idx}"; done 
}

# OPTIMIZED by anishsane 
find_index_anishsane () {

   awk 'NR==1{a=$0; next} #Record first line
     NR==FNR{ #For entire first pass,
         while(match($0, a)!=1) #Find the common part in string
             a=substr(a,1,length(a)-1); 
         next;
     }
     # In second pass
     FNR==1{a=length(a)} # This is just an optimization. You could also use sub/gensub based logic

     {print substr($0,a+1)} # Print the substring 
     ' $tempf $tempf
}

# OPTIMIZED by 123 
find_index_123 () {
    awk 'NR==1{
           pos=split($0,a,"")
     }
     NR==FNR{
          split($0,b,"")
          for(i=1;i<=pos;i++)
             if(b[i]!=a[i]){
                pos=i
                break
           }
           next
        }
    NR!=FNR{
       print substr($0,pos)
    }' $tempf $tempf
}

echo "--- BASELINE (run once)"
time find_index_baseline > /dev/null # even slow when running once :) 
echo "---- ANISHSANE x100"
time for i in {1..100}; do find_index_anishsane > /dev/null; done
echo "---- 123 x100"
time for i in {1..100}; do find_index_123 > /dev/null; done

rm -f $tempf
```

Output is..

```
--- BASELINE (run once)

real    0m1.186s
user    0m0.481s
sys     0m1.283s
---- ANISHSANE x100

real    0m2.277s
user    0m1.024s
sys     0m1.301s
---- 123 x100

real    0m1.984s
user    0m0.772s
sys     0m1.092s
```

Comment: I don't really understand how you got that output or what the logic is, could you explain in a little more detail please ?

Comment: You mean how I found the solution in my implementation?

Comment: Doesn't matter, i think i sort of understand after rereading it a few times. How big is the file ?

Comment: I updated the code with some more documentation. Well, not that much. Usually something around 10-15 lines.

Comment: I suspect any solution will end up not using the shell language but rather something equally readily available. Maybe sed or awk or Perl or Python.

Comment: That would be totally fine. I only care about performance. I have bash 4 and the usual tools at my command :)

Comment: Check `expr index $string $substring` section in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html (or check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/041 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USing two passes and capturing the furthest along one on the first pass.

```
awk 'NR==1{
           pos=split($0,a,"")
     }
     NR==FNR{
          split($0,b,"")
          for(i=1;i<=pos;i++)
             if(b[i]!=a[i]){
                pos=i
                break
           }
           next
        }
    NR!=FNR{
       print substr($0,pos)
    }' file{,}
```

Should be very quick

#### TEST

```
$ for i in {1..10000};do echo -e "blablabla this is always the same 123\nblablabla this is always the same 321\nblablabla this is always the same 4242\nblablabla this is al 242\nblablabla this is always 2432" >> test;done

$ wc -l < test
  50000
```

Timing on my machine for 50000 lines

```
real    0m1.444s
user    0m0.888s
sys     0m0.080s
```

Comment: Thanks 123! That's even a tat faster on my machine than anishsane's version.

Comment: Currently you're the winner! ;) .

Comment: @JohnDoe It appears mine is quickest for small amounts of data but slowest for large...

Comment: Imho the benchmark should fit the use case. In my case, I don't require this for large data sets but for many repetitions.

Comment: @BastiTee If your use case is to deal with many repetitions, the very first thing you should do is to filter out the distinct lists (e.g. `sort | uniq`).

Comment: Didn't think of it, because it doesn't apply for me, but you're totally  right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python solution which does the job:

```
from itertools import izip, takewhile
import sys

def allEqual(x):
    return not x or len(x) == x.count(x[0])

lines = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
prefixLen = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(allEqual, izip(*set(lines))))
for l in lines:
    print l[prefixLen:]
```

The `allEquals` function tells if all elements in the given sequence (e.g. a tuple or a list) are equal (or if the sequence is empty). The `commonPrefixLength` function takes a sequence of strings and returns the length of the longest common prefix. Finally, the main program reads from `stdin`, determines the length of the longest common prefix and prints all input lines except for the common prefix.

This seems to be a faster than the awk-based solutions so far, e.g.:

```
$ for i in {1..10000};do echo -e "blablabla this is always the same 123\nblablabla this is always the same 321\nblablabla this is always the same 4242\nblablabla this is al 242\nblablabla this is always 2432" >> testdata.txt;done
$ time awk -f 123.awk testdata.txt{,} > /dev/null

real    0m3.858s
user    0m3.826s
sys 0m0.030s
$ time awk -f anishane.awk testdata.txt testdata.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0.517s
user    0m0.511s
sys 0m0.005s
$ time python frerich.py < testdata.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.082s
sys 0m0.014s
```

They generate equal output, too:

```
$ awk -f anishane.awk testdata.txt testdata.txt | md5
8a3880cb99a388092dd549c8dc4a9cc3
$ awk -f 123.awk testdata.txt{,} | md5
8a3880cb99a388092dd549c8dc4a9cc3
$ python frerich.py < testdata.txt | md5
8a3880cb99a388092dd549c8dc4a9cc3
```

Comment: Faster than mine, although you have a typo with `line` and then use `lines` everywhere else.

Comment: @123: Indeed, fixed the typo now. Also, note that your program actually does something different than anishane's and mine. The output is different.

Comment: How is the output different ?

Comment: It's a nice solution, but unfortunately I cannot use it in my scenario.

Comment: @123 For me, your program merely prints the numbers 3, 1, 42 in a loop.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I messed something up for like 10 seconds when editing before, you must have copied that code, does it have `FNR==1` at the start

Comment: @123 Ah indeed, it appears I copied the broken version. now your program generates the same output. I included it now in my primitive benchmark.

Comment: Yep, mine sucks for bigger data sets, probably because it compares every character for every line, good solution btw!

Comment: I adjusted my solution a bit now (making it about twice as fast) after realizing that for computing the longest common prefix, I don't need to consider all lines but only distinct lines (this helps a lot with the described use case, when there are many repetitions).

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0; next} #Record first line
     NR==FNR{ #For entire first pass,
         while(match($0, a)!=1) #Find the common part in string
             a=substr(a,1,length(a)-1); 
         next;
     }
     # In second pass
     FNR==1{a=length(a)} # This is just an optimization. You could also use sub/gensub based logic

     {print substr($0,a+1)} # Print the substring 
     ' test-input.log test-input.log # Pass the file twice


ways the same 123
ways the same 321
ways the same 4242
 242
ways 2432
```

`time` outputs:

```
Bash based code:
real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s

awk based code:
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: You must have posted just as i started writing :(, do you reckon the answers are different enough to use both ?

Comment: @anishsane Wow, this is blazing fast! Thanks. I will upvote this and update my initial code with the comparison of both ways. On my machine the performance gain is even more than factor 10.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think for actual benchmarks you'll want larger input data sets.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Imho the benchmark should fit the use case. In my case, I don't require this for large data sets but for many repetitions.

Comment: I agree with @FrerichRaabe. I did not check with larger data set.